# Database design for user medias

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am creating site where users can upload images and videos like on facebook. But I have two ideas and i wonder which is better:
1)

```
UserMedias{userid, mediaid...}
Medias{mediaid,mediaTypeId,name,url...}
MediaTypes{MediaTypeId,name...}
```

2)

```
UserImages{userid, imageid...}
Image{imageid,name...}
UserVideos{userid,videoid...}
Videos{videoid,name...}
```

Comment: I would go with the first implementation since it allows better, faster joins, at least from how I understand the issue.

Comment: Performance is what interested me the most.

Comment: What are your use cases?  Your design should reflect the overall flow of the program.

Comment: Your second attempt might make use of foreign keys nicely, but so can the first, it all depends on how bloated your tables get. I'd go with the first implementation until I have a reason not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First implementation has following Pros:

- as Khez said, it will allow faster
  join
- it does not require you to change
  schema if you want to include audio
  later on.

Both video and photo have same attributes other than the fact that they are physically different.

Answer (score 1):

First option. Just make sure your software can handle each media type in MediaTypes table.